# Cannot import Imread from Pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, importerror

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from PIL import Image
from skimage import feature
```

I reinstalled Windows 10, so I had to reinstall Anaconda and Jupyter also.

I usually use these import statements, however, now I'm getting an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'imread' from 'pylab'
>   (C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylab__init__.py)

Do you have any suggestions? I have installed Pylab, PIL and Matplotlib already.

Comment: Wat is the name of the python script you are executing?

Comment: It's Python 3.7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
```

in stead of:

```
from pylab import imread
```